# Trying to append List/array based on condition

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to add to an array based on a condition.
Can someone clarify why the if statement isn't working as I intend it to?

```
all_staff = ["Judith", "Harry", "Jonathan", "Reuben"]
new_staff = []


def person_finder(staff):
for x in staff:
    if x == "Reuben" or "Harry" or "Jonathan":
        new_staff.append(x)
    else:
        continue
    return new_staff


selected = person_finder(all_staff)


def the_men(people):
for x in people:
    print(x + " is a man")


the_men(selected)
```

This returns:

Judith is a man

Comment: What are the downvotes for?

Comment: Put `new_staff = []` first thing inside `person_finder`. Change `if x == "Reuben" or "Harry" or "Jonathan"` to `if x in ["Reuben", "Harry", "Jonathan"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all_staff = ["Judith", "Harry", "Jonathan", "Reuben"]


def person_finder(staff):
    new_staff = []
    for x in staff:
        if x in ["Reuben", "Harry", "Jonathan"]:
            new_staff.append(x)
        else:
            continue
    return new_staff


selected = person_finder(all_staff)


def the_men(people):
    for x in people:
        print(x + " is a man")


the_men(selected)
```

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
if x == "Reuben" or "Harry" or "Jonathan":
```

with

```
if x == "Reuben" or x == "Harry" or x == "Jonathan":
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line :

```
if x == "Reuben" or "Harry" or "Jonathan":
```

to

```
if x == "Reuben" or x=="Harry" or x=="Jonathan":
```

Working code:

```
all_staff = ["Judith", "Harry", "Jonathan", "Reuben"]

new_staff = []


def person_finder(staff):
    for x in staff:
        if x == "Reuben" or x=="Harry" or x=="Jonathan":
            new_staff.append(x)
        else:
            continue
    return new_staff


selected = person_finder(all_staff)


def the_men(people):
    for x in people:
        print(x + " is a man")


the_men(selected)
```

output:

```
Harry is a man
Jonathan is a man
Reuben is a man
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @MrKeystrokes its working , check my edited answer.